# Using babel, typeof returns "object" instead of class name

Tags: ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

Consider

```
class A {}
// somewhere in a a test using mocha.js with babel es2105 preset on

const a = new A();
assert.ok(typeof(a) === "A");
```

This test fails. Looking into it, it turns out that typeof returns "object" instead of "A", which causes the test to fail. Thus, babel erronously transforms typeof calls.

I tried using the [ES2015 typeof symbol transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-typeof-symbol/), but this did not help. Looking at the code, it only does thi correctly for Symbol instances. So that makes sense.

How to fix to achieve the correct behavior?

Comment: This is correct behavior.

Comment: You're right, and this is unexpected (what's new in JS, lol).

Comment: Symbol is new primitive type, thats why `typeof Symbol()` is `'symbol'` Compared to say `typeof new Map()`  or `typeof new RegExp()`

Answer (score 1):

It's correct behaviour. `a` is an object, an instance of `A`, which probably is what you're looking for:

```
assert.ok(a.constructor.name === 'A')
```

Comment: It is indeed correct behavior, but still unexpected :).